# How to plot a confusion matrix

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix

I am trying to evaluate my renet50 model with a confusion matrix, but the confusion matrix looks like this:

```
matrix = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred, normalize="pred")
print(matrix)
    
# output
array([[1, 0],
      [1, 2]], dtype=int64)
```

I am using scikit-learn for generating the confusion matrix and tf keras for making the model

but is there any way I can plot/visualize the confusion matrix?

i already try using `sklearn.metrics.plot_confusion_matrix(matrix)`

and this: [How to plot Confusion Matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71232646/how-to-plot-confusion-matrix)
but I got this:

[image: tutorial from stackoverflow]

Comment: `from sklearn.metrics import ConfusionMatrixDisplay` call the function and pass your matrix as an argument, like this: `disp = ConfusionMatrixDisplay(confusion_matrix=matrix)` then just plot it: `disp.plot()` and show it. Hopefully, that is what you are looking for. Check out the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.ConfusionMatrixDisplay.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include the following imports:

```
from sklearn.metrics import ConfusionMatrixDisplay 
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
```

Now, call the `ConfusionMatrixDisplay` function and pass your `matrix` as an argument, like this:

```
disp = ConfusionMatrixDisplay(confusion_matrix=matrix) 
# Then just plot it: 
disp.plot() 
# And show it: 
plt.show()
```

Additionally, you can set the `normalize` parameter to `True` in the `ConfusionMatrixDisplay` function to display the normalized counts in the plot. Check out the [docs](https://%20https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.ConfusionMatrixDisplay.html) for further reference and additional accepted parameters.